# OpenGL .so Logcat - OpenGL primitives in APK needs to be logged to Logcat

Tags: android, opengl-es, .so

With Android 4.4.3 we have a OpenGL Canvas which displays a image having annotted text. The application code uses OpenGLES2.0 with Vivante GC2000 GPU.

In trying to get the rendered text on the Image we note that OCR fails with MDPI(160DPI). Now a valid solution is to not modify the APK but modify the OpenGL_CM_Viviante.so file in the /system/lib folder.

OpenGL trace fails to list the GLPrimitive to enter the text, but we feel that modifing the .so file to either send the entered text to Logcat or to a COM port should work.

Is this a Feasible solution?. Any specific steps to go about this would be appreciated

Some Links relevent to the Topic:
OpenGL Primitives by OHA: osxr.org:8080/android/ident?_i=glDiscardFramebufferEXT&_remember=1
.SO files Used: www.2net.co.uk/tutorial/android-egl-cgf-is-dead

I am now looking at the canvas.drawBitmap and  canvas.drawText methods as per this fractiousg.blogspot.in/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion changing the library is not a good solution if your requirement is to draw a text on a image use simple canvas.drawtext on bitmap you mentioned

Comment: canvas.drawtext is used to provide an annotation marker on the Image(OpenGL Surfaceview). This Image is at low DPI and we cannot extract text from the display at the moment. The plan is to log the text when the annotation is made to a log/logcat or to UART. Is this feasible/possible?. How much effort would overriding the drawtext method(inside the .so file) take?. Is this